# R: Change objects inside loop

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, apply, lapply

```
a <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2))
b <- data.frame(x = c(3, 4))

for (df in list(a, b)) {
  print(df)
  df$y <- c(5, 6)
}
```

Each of the data frames gets printed out correctly, but adding an additional column fails.
Extensive web search suggested something like

```
lapply(list(a, b), function(df){
  df$y <- c(5, 6)
})
```

but this didn't help me.

What I'd be also very interested is, why the print statement in the `for` loop works, but the addition of the `y` column fails.

This is surprising for me.

Comment: not able to understand what you want as the output here. Could you detail on that?

Comment: Often, when you want to edit multiple objects, you also want to store them in a list. E.g. `my_list <- list(a = a, b = b)`. Then you can do `my_list <- lapply(my_list, ...)` as much as you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to return the `df`'s with that additional column.
Try:

```
lapply(list(a, b), function(df){
  df$y <- c(5, 6); return(df)
})
```

The output is:

```
[[1]]
  x y
1 1 5
2 2 6

[[2]]
  x y
1 3 5
2 4 6
```

As @dash2 supposes you may want to assign those changed `df`'s to your `list` of `df`'s. So the full code could look like:

```
a <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2))
b <- data.frame(x = c(3, 4))

l <- list(a, b)
l <- lapply(l, function(df){ df$y <- c(5, 6); return(df) })
```

Comment: And then you probably want to assign the results to the original, so something like `my_list <- lapply...; a <- my_list[[1]]; b <- my_list[[2]]`

Comment: Thank's a lot for your answer, which definitely works. I had actually hoped there is a shorter solution, because in case one has just 2 data.frame, then it's probably still easier and more readable to do `a$y <- c(5,6)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
> a <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2))
> b <- data.frame(x = c(3, 4))
> l <- list(a = a, b = b)
> list2env(lapply(l, function(x) {x$y <- c(5, 6);x}), envir = .GlobalEnv)
<environment: R_GlobalEnv>
> a
  x y
1 1 5
2 2 6
> b
  x y
1 3 5
2 4 6
```